# Open XML SDK for JavaScript spreadsheeml

Tags: javascript, openxml-sdk, spreadsheetml

I am creating excel spreadsheet by using Open XML SDK for javascript. used below script to add spreadsheet data.

[Open XML SDK Javascript](https://openxmlsdkjs.codeplex.com/)

```
var table = wsXDoc.descendants(openXml.S.sheetData).firstOrDefault();

var newRow = new Ltxml.XElement(openXml.S.row,
             new Ltxml.XAttribute("r", 1));

table.add(newRow);

var cell = new Ltxml.XElement(openXml.S.c,
           new Ltxml.XAttribute("r", "A1"),
           Ltxml.XElement(openXml.S.v, number));

newRow.add(cell);
```

The above code works fine when i pass number as value. it throws error when i pass text as value.

How to create string based cell?

Another question:

How to apply cell style through open xml sdk javascript?

Answer (score 0):

http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2013/12/16/advice-when-generating-spreadsheets-use-inline-strings-not-shared-strings.aspx

```
var cell = new XElement(S.c, new XAttribute("r", "A3"), new XAttribute("t", "inlineStr"), new XElement(S._is, new XElement(S.t, "HELLO WORLD")));
```

Thanks for your code and here is your solution.